# How to Convert SQL Server bigint to timestamp using java code

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jakarta-ee, sql-server-2008-r2

I have got  bigint data from database query like below

duebydate:1302017399984

I want to convert the above duebydate to timestamp using java code

Could any one help?

I knew that in SQL Server we can use predefined functions to convert to timestamp

Comment: The logic is usually something like:  divide by 1000 and add (in seconds) to 1970-01-01.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the SimpleDateFormat class:

```
String value = "1302017399984"; 
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
format.setLenient(false);
Date date = format.parse(value);
```